# Dynamically created message reference in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

So I have the following code:

```
 <h3 th:if="#{${'footer.message.' + receiptProperties.url}? : '(NOTHING)'}"  th:utext="#{${'footer.message.' + receiptProperties.url}}"></h3>
```

**receiptProperties.url** = a name given to a tenant, such as ABC, DEF etc. So the key in the messages.properties file would be something like **footer.message.ABC**=Hello ABC!

The dynamically created message key displays correctly, however, if the key such as **footer.message.GHI** does not exist in the properties file, then instead of not displaying anything at all, the following is shown on the page: **??footer.message.GHI_en??**

Is there any way in Thymeleaf to accurately check if the *dynamically* created key exists in the properties file?

Answer (score 11):

The [messages utility](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#messages-1) object has methods that can be used for this.  You could use an expression like:

```
${#messages.msgOrNull('footer.message.' + receiptProperties.url) == null ? 'Invalid key' : 'Valid key'}
```